# How to get the specific result from text file?

Tags: c, function, fetch

I am facing a problem. Whenever I want to fetch something and type that word, the result gives the complete sentence after that word. Means it starts from that word and print the whole sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  FILE * fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
  const char string[100];
  char found[100];
  char *result;
  const char fetch[11] = "learning";

  while(fgets(string, 100, fp))
  {
    strcpy(found, string);
    printf("Your result: %s", found);

    result = strstr(found, fetch);
    printf("Your result is: %s",result);
    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us the input, the expected output as well as the actual output. And please, to simplify things (and really make a [mcve]) you could hard-code the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strstr` returns a pointer to the position of the search word if *it exists*, otherwise it will return `NULL`.  However, `strstr()` leaves the position of the null terminator ( `\0` ) at the end of the buffer being searched.  Extracting the search word, requires the null terminator be moved to mark the end of word.

*Method 1:* - Tokenize string
There are many ways to do this.  This one uses parsing to tokenize the original line content into its component sub-strings using spaces as delimiters, while using `strcmp()` to test each *token* for the `fetch` sub-string specifically. The following illustration includes a function that does this:

```
char * extract_sub_string(char *in, const char *key);

int main(void)
{
    char buf[100] = {0};    

    sprintf(buf, "Found sub_string: %s\n", extract_sub_string(line, fetch));

  return 0;
}

char * extract_sub_string(char *in, const char *key)
{
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(in, " ");
    while(tok)
    {
        if(strcmp(tok, key) == 0)
        {
            in = tok;//re-assign ptr to found string
            break;
        }
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return in;
}
```

*Method 2:* - Pointer and length

Again, to  capture the single word after it's location has been determined in the line, a `\0` must be placed after the last character of that word.  Because we can get the length of `fetch` using: `strlen(fetch)+1`, it can be used in the following expression to extract the word. ( `+1` places the `\0` character *after* the last character of the found word)

```
result = strstr(found, fetch);
if(result)//if result is NULL, bypass the extraction
{
    result[strlen(fetch) + 1)] = `\0`;
    printf("Your result is: %s",result);
}
```

*Method 3* - An in-line adaptation of your post using tokens.

```
  ...//insert into your original code
  char *tok = NULL;

  while(fgets(string, 100, fp))
  {
    tok = strtok(string, " ");//use space as a delimiter
    while(tok)//tok is not null
    {
        if(strcmp(fetch, tok) == 0)//test for target word
        {
            strcpy(found, tok);//if found, output it.
            printf("Your result: %s", found);
            break;//leave the loop
        }
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");//if not found yet, keep looking.
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how strings in C work. A string is a sequence of characters terminated by the *null-terminator* (the `'\0'` character).

If [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) finds the sub-string it returns a pointer to the *first* character in the full string, but by using that pointer the string doesn't end until the null-terminator of the full string.

Example:

Lets say the input is the string

```
It's fun learning C
```

then that will in memory look something like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| I | t | ' | s |   | f | u | n |   | l | e | a | r | n | i | n | g |   | C | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

When you call `strstr` it will return a pointer to the `l` character in `learning`:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| I | t | ' | s |   | f | u | n |   | l | e | a | r | n | i | n | g |   | C | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
                                    ^
+--------+                          |
| result | -------------------------/
+--------+
```

---

Now when you hopefully understand what's going on and what's happening, it's time to think about how to only display the sub-string you searched for. And the simplest solution is simply to print the search-string `fetch`:

```
printf("Your result is: %s\n", fetch);
```

If you want to print the position (index) of where the sub-string was found, then you can simply subtract the (decayed) pointer of `found` from `result`:

```
printf("Found the sub-string '%s' at index %td\n", fetch, found - result);
```

<sub>[The [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format `%td` is used to print a [`ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t) value, which is the type of the result of pointer subtraction]</sub>

You should also be careful to check that `strstr` really found the sub-string, otherwise it will return `NULL` and you can't dereference or use the `NULL` pointer in any meaningful way.

Comment: I don't want to print the fetch varialble. I want to first to be found in file then print

Comment: @natashaBibi Think about it a little bit... The `fetch` string contains `"learning"`. If you find the location in `found` and extract it into its own array (or terminate after word in `found`) you have the string... `"learning"`. What is the difference what you print? The result shown to the user will still be the word `learning`. Sure you can do `result[strlen(fetch)] = '\0'; printf("Your result is: %s\n", result);` but there's no difference from the string `fetch`.

Comment: Actually I am using that found variable somewhere else also and that's why I need it. The code is big. I just printed some of lines. By the way thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @natashaBibi Then the problem is: Do you want to modify `found`? Or do you need to copy the sub-string into a new string? If you modify `found` you basically loose everything after the found word. And if you copy the found string then why not use `fetch` instead of copy? Anyway, you know the alternatives, now it's up to you to pick the one that fit your use-case best.

Comment: I am actually copying the string to use `strstr` to find specific word from that string, that's I tried to copy it in another variable.

Comment: @natashaBibi I'm sorry for nagging, but if you want to copy the word from `found` to a new string, then why not simply use `fetch` which already contains the word? If you get the sub-string from `found` and it's contents is `"learning"`, and you have `fetch` which contents is `"learning"`, i.e. exactly the same, why bother with the copying? Just use `fetch` and its contents.

Comment: I know but I copied the string in another variable to use `strstr` to find specific word from that string. It is temporary. If I used found fetch variable in `strstr`, will it be okay?

Comment: @natashaBibi As long as you do not modify it, then you can use `strstr` to see if a sub-string is found, and then use `fetch` to reference the sub-string itself.